# Raspberry pi hosting d.js bot

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, discord.js

So hi, I am discord.js bot developer and I am trying to host my bot on raspberry pi 4.

error:

```
/home/raspberrymeow/Documents/olex7imatix.org-bot/o7im.org-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32
    const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/raspberrymeow/Documents/olex7imatix.org-bot/o7im.org-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

more info:
raspberry pi 4 2 gb ram
discord.js v 13 (npm and node installed yet)
packages:

```
"@discordjs/builders": "^1.2.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^1.1.0",
    "ascii-table": "^0.0.9",
    "canvas": "^2.10.1",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.37.10",
    "discord.js": "^13.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you running on (You can find out using `node -v`)? Looks like you must have Node >16 according to this issue:
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/6357

Comment: how to update it to node > 16 in linux?

Comment: and There's anothere error
```

Comment: ```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './RateLimitError'
Require stack:
- /home/raspberrymeow/Documents/olex7imatix.org-bot/o7im.org-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js
- /home/raspberrymeow/Documents/olex7imatix.org-bot/o7im.org-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js
- /home/raspberrymeow/Documents/olex7imatix.org-bot/o7im.org-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/raspberrymeow/Documents/olex7imatix.org-bot/o7im.org-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /home/raspberrymeow/```

Comment: It's too long bruh

Comment: You can update using ``n``:
https://askubuntu.com/a/480642